# Kubernetes - NotReady node with ContainerGCFailed warning

Tags: kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks, argo-workflows, argo

**Kubernetes version** : 1.23 
**Container runtime**: Docker

`kubectl describe node node1`

```
  Type     Reason             Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  ContainerGCFailed  2m35s (x507 over 9h)  kubelet  rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: trying to send message larger than max (16777539 vs. 16777216)
```

**Worker node details** 
`df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            32G  1.1M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  200G   36G  165G  18% /
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

`docker system df`

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          27        26        18.23GB   1.433GB (7%)
Containers      24577     11        1.333GB   1.333GB (100%)
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

Using `argo-workflows` as container orchestration engine on Amazon EKS, I have enough space on worker nodes and no issues with memory/CPUs, issue might be because of lot of dead containers on worker nodes(24577 generated by argo workflows). In earlier versions of `kubelet` configuration, there is an option to delete dead containers `--maximum-dead-containers` but it is deprecated now and it is replaced with `--eviction-hard` or `--eviction-soft` settings, with available eviction settings I can only configure `memory` `nodefs` `pid` eviction signals

How to specify `--maximum-dead-containers` or equivalent signal using updated `--eviction-hard` or `--eviction-soft` settings ?

`kubeletConfiguration` : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/

If I connect to worker node and run `docker system prune` on worker node, it becomes available but it deletes all  the workflow logs, we want to keep logs for 7 days at least

Comment: The documentation is misleading. I think you need to use `imageMinimumGCAge`, `imageGCHighThresholdPercent`, and `imageGCLowTHresholdPercent`. Either that or you should set a [TTL](https://v1-26.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/#updating-ttl-for-finished-jobs) for jobs. Incidentally, you can use deprecated features/flags until they're removed.

Comment: Thanks, but how does `imageGCHighThresholdPercent` and `imageGCLowTHresholdPercent` helpful here? I have only used 35GB out of 200GB(only 18%), do I have to set the limits to max 35GB and min 30GB? I did set `TTL` on the job level to delete all pods after 7 days, since it is our main workflow engine we might need pods for at least 7 days for debugging purposes

Comment: I don't see how using `--eviction-hard` and `--eviction-soft` is going to help here. I'd experiment with the image settings. If all else fails, you can continue using `--maximum-dead-containers` until the flag is removed.